# PHP get value from dropdown menu on next page in multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the value from a dropdown menu on the next page after the form has been submitted?

Please have a look at my code and tell me what am i doing wrong...?

I am assigning 2 values from a database to an array called $opponents as such:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
     $opponents[] = array('oppname' => $row['opponents'], 'oppid' => $row['fixture_id']) ; 
}
```

I then extract the value of the array $opponents as such

```
foreach ($opponents as $opp) {
    $opponent_name[] = $opp['oppname'];
     echo '<option value="'.$opp['oppid'].'">'.$opp['oppname'].'</option>';
}
```

Now **when the form has been submitted** I call the $opponents array like this:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['opponents'] as $oppname){
 print $oppname;
 }
```

**It is working but it gives me the opponents_id and not the opponent_name.** How do I go about getting the name out of the $opponents array while also keeping the id?

Thanxs in advance

Comment: The option value is the $opp['oppid'], for sure you got the ID in $_REQUEST[]. Either you put $opp['oppname'] in the value of the <option/> tag, or lookup the oppname using the oppid again from your database / memory cache.

Comment: Thank you that helped me, just had to change my logic slightly.